# Overwritting the file using FileOutputStream in java

Tags: java, spring, file

I am trying to write the content from specific pages of a pdf document into another file. I am trying it y using the below code

```
ByteArrayInputStream[] stream = pdfFileEditorObj
                    .splitToBulks("E:\\JavaProjects\\docs\\Latest\\Workflow_Services.pdf", numberOfPage);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("E:\\JavaProjects\\docs\\Latest\\Workflow_Services1.pdf", true);

    for (ByteArrayInputStream bStream : stream) {
         IOUtils.copy(bStream, out);
         out.flush();
         out.close();

    }
```

but its overwriting the exsisting file. I am able to see only the last page content.

Can any body help on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: `out.close()` should be outside the `for` cycle.

Comment: I have given it as true while creating the FileOutputStream. but it is still over writting

Comment: I have put out.close() outside the for loop. still the same.

Comment: You don't need to call `flush()` because `close()` always flushes first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a page to a PDF document just by appending the binary contents of a stream to the end of a file, as you are doing. PDF files contain metadata and you need to treat them as such. Instead of appending a byte stream to the end of a file, use [concatenate](https://apireference.aspose.com/java/pdf/com.aspose.pdf.facades/PdfFileEditor#concatenate-java.io.InputStream:A-java.io.OutputStream-):

```
ByteArrayInputStream[] streams = pdfFileEditorObj
                    .splitToBulks("E:\\JavaProjects\\docs\\Latest\\Workflow_Services.pdf", numberOfPage);

pdfFileEditorObj.concatenate(streams, new FileOutputStream("E:\\JavaProjects\\docs\\Latest\\Workflow_Services1.pdf");
```

The above creates a new file. If you want to append pages to an existing file:

1. Read the existing file and create an ArrayList of streams.
2. Append to that ArrayList the array of streams you want to append to the file.
3. Call concatenate using the new array.